# arm-linux-gnueabi toolchain vs arm-linux-androideabi toolchain.

Tags: linux, compilation, android-ndk, toolchain

Can I compile files (e.g. C or C++ source code) using for my android device using the `arm-linux-gnueabi-*` toolchain?

My question might seem a bit silly, but will I get the same result as compiling with the `arm-linux-androideabi-*` toolchain?

Comment: you can use any arm-toolchain for arm-architecture will work for you.(just remember 32-bit/64-bit difference)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A compilation might mean more than just converting source code to binary. A compiler like GCC also provides certain libraries, in this case [libgcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Libgcc.html) for handling what hardware can't handle. When a compiler becomes a toolchain, it also provides runtime libraries standardised by the programming language similar to ones provided in target system. In `arm-linux-gnueabi-`'s case that might be [libc](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/libc.html) and for `arm-linux-androideabi-` that's [bionic](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master).

You can produce compatible object files to be used by different compilers, that's what [elf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) is for.

You can produce static executable which can be mighty in size and they should work on any matching hardware/kernel, because in that case toolchains aim for that.

But if you produce dynamic executables, those ones can only run on systems that's supporting their dependencies. Because of that a simple "hello world" application that's not static build by `arm-linux-gnueabi-` won't work on an Android system since it provides bionic, not libc.